# How can I compile an Erlang file with includes from the erl shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

`erlc -I <abspath-to-include-dir> <module>.erl` on the command line correctly compiles `<module>`

But in the Erlang shell (`erl`), the following produces errors with "cannot find include file":

`c(<module>, [{i, <abspath-to-include-dir>}]).`

Why? Shouldn't the behavior of these two ways of compiling files be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the path as a list of directories, as in `{i, [".../here/", ".../there/"]}`, even if it's just a single directory.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Sometimes I wish the shell were type-aware.